# Selenium Java to compare UI data with Excel data

Tags: java, selenium

What would be a simple set of Java lines in Selenium to validate data from Excel data and compare with UI.

Scenario is:
Multiple rows on UI - Fname, Lname, Age, Phone
Multiple rows in Excel - Fname, Lname, Age, Phone

I have @DataProvider which returns Excel data line by line. So the test below runs as many times as the number of records in Excel. But I'm having an issue with the if statement within the test which validates the values. It compares the first record, but how to validate the subsequent runs?

```
   @Test(dataProvider="ExcelData")
    public void excelTest(String fName,String lName,...){
      String frontEnd_fName = driver.get(...);
        if (frontEnd_fName.equals(Fname))
           {
              System.out.println("name matches");
           }
        else
          {
             System.out.println("name does not match");
          }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add an index column to your excel data?